# Override default handling of application/json requests in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, ajax, json

ASP.NET 3.5 and 4 are both catching requests with Content-Type "application/json" and I don't want them to. I think they're trying to find a WebMethod in the code-behind or something, but I don't really care. This is NOT ASP MVC. How can I prevent conventional ASP.NET from behaving this way?